# How to define schema for array which get repeat multiple time which mark my test case fail

Tags: api, karate

**Schema:**

{"ABC":[
{
"pqr":"#string",
"XYZ":[
{
"a":"#string",
"b":"#string"
"c":"#number"
]
}

**Question:** Above is my schema but in response I am getting XYZ block repeating 11 times so that fail my test case. How we can define that schema in karate?

Defined my schema like below

- def expschema =

{"ABC":[
{
"pqr":"#string",
"XYZ":[
{
"a":"#string",
"b":"#string"
"c":"#number"

}

In Response I am getting like

{"ABC":[
{
"pqr":"#string",
"XYZ":[
{
"a":"Text",
"b":"Text1"
"c":"1"

}
{
"a":"Text2",
"b":"Text2"
"c":"2"

}
{
"a":"Text3",
"b":"Text3"
"c":"3"

}
{
"a":"Text4",
"b":"Text4"
"c":"4"

}
{
"a":"Text5",
"b":"Text5"
"c":"5"

}
{
"a":"Text6",
"b":"Text6"
"c":"6"

}

My test case failed as in response one array repeat multiple time so how to define that in schema so it should work always irrespective of number of times array value repeats.

Comment: Thanks for responding but somehow still thats not answering my question. I want to do schema validation & one array having 4 field with string & number as per schema but in response in same array its repeating those 4 field as jason object in that array multiple times with different value & count may differ not required to be same every time. How we can define that schema. Below example not answering this question or not have that scenario covered. [link]https://github.com/intuit/karate#schema-validation